# Weird padding on View in react native web on Edge

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, microsoft-edge

I was creating a Button in react native (on web). If I view the button in Edge, a very weird padding appears. I tried to debug but I can't get a fix. It works correctly on Android and Firefox.

I think there is some problem with Edge's renderer (Blink) because the code works correctly in firefox and on android (native).

Here is the code for the component:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Animated, Easing, Image, StyleSheet, Pressable, Text } from 'react-native';

import { Hoverable } from 'react-native-web-hooks';

const Button = () => {
    const [animatedButtonPressed] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
    const [animatedButtonHover] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));

    const animate = (value, toValue, duration = 150, easing = Easing.linear) => {
        Animated.timing(value, {
            toValue: toValue,
            duration: duration,
            easing: easing,
            // change later
            useNativeDriver: false
        }).start();
    }

    const animatedTextStyle = {
        color: animatedButtonPressed.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0,1],
            outputRange: ["#fff" , "#2b7f3c"]
        })
    }

    const animatedButtonStyle = {
        backgroundColor: animatedButtonHover.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0,1],
            outputRange: ["#2b7f3c", "transparent"]
        }),
    }

    const animatedButtonPressedStyle = {
        backgroundColor: animatedButtonPressed.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0,1],
            outputRange: ["#fff", "red"]
        }),
    }

    let Handlers = (props) => {
        return (
            <>
                <Pressable onPressIn={() => animate(animatedButtonPressed, 1)} onPressOut={() => animate(animatedButtonPressed, 0)}>
                    <Hoverable onHoverIn={() => animate(animatedButtonHover, 1)} onHoverOut={() => animate(animatedButtonHover, 0)}>
                        <View {...props}/>
                    </Hoverable>
                </Pressable>
            </>
        )
    }

    let Backgrounds = (props) => {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={animatedButtonPressedStyle}>
                <Animated.View style={animatedButtonStyle}>
                    <View {...props}/>
                </Animated.View>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Backgrounds>
                    <Handlers>
                        <View style={styles.padding}>
                            <Animated.Text style={[styles.text, animatedTextStyle]}>Hello</Animated.Text>
                        </View>
                    </Handlers>
                </Backgrounds>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flexDirection: 'row', 
        alignSelf: 'flex-start',
        overflow: 'hidden',
    },
    button: {
        borderRadius: 3,
        borderWidth: 2,
        borderColor: 'green',
    },
    padding: {
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        paddingVertical: 5,
    },
    text: {
        color: 'white',
        fontSize: 16
    }
});

export default Button;
```

[image: Here is a side-by-side view of Edge and Firefox]

Answer (score 0):

I think this is unfortunately a symptom of using React-native on the web things get squashed and you won't have as much control for cross browser quirks.

Is there any reason you didn't use ReactJS?

Comment: No. I think it's a problem with Blink itself. It has some weird layout bugs. I couldn't use ReactJS only because the client want a native app that also works on the web and since I have some React knowledge; Native was the way to go.

Comment: @vixalien The blink engine is definitely the problem but in web development, you can compensate for those styling issues with specific CSS rules for that browser. 

The way you deal with Styles in React-native is that they get squashed down until interpreted "best practice".  That's fine for Android and iOS with smaller ecosystems but browsers are a minefield when it comes to styling